# Retrieve json data object with @

Tags: php, json, oop, class, object

How can I return values that has key name '@' Using PHP

```
[directory] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [@id] => 87e0cfeb-e7ea-4814-80ac-a98f770811eb
                    [@title] => _root
                    [@hasClips] => 1
                )
```

Comment: What programming language is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$your_variable->{"@id"}
```